# How to link multiple HTML pages resides in assets folder in android?

Tags: android, html, hyperlink

I am new to Android.

I want to display HTML pages in android emulator. I put my "test1.html" and "test2.html" files in the "assets" folder and managed to display "test1.html" file in Android by using the following code.

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Test extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);

        try {

            InputStream fin = getAssets().open("test1.html");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fin.available()];
                fin.read(buffer);
                fin.close();
                webview.loadData(new String(buffer), "text/html", "UTF-8");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to click a button or a link in the "test1.html" file and open the "test2.html" file.How can I link those two HTML pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button` or `Link` in `test1.html` should just work like normal html file. Make sure when you provide the path for `test2.html` is right with respect to `test1.html` since they are in assets directory.

Edit your code like this

```
<a href="file:///android_asset/test2.html">Next Page</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I also tried that. But it gives me the error "Web page not available". Any idea about the error?

Comment: What's the path are you giving for test2.html file?

Comment: <a href="test2.html">Next Page</a> in "test1.html" page

Comment: I have added the code for your reference where you should change your test2.html file path. If this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: It is not working. No error or any other output. 

I'm using an input stream to pass the "test1.html" file. Do I need to create another input stream for the "test2.html" as well? If so, how should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do a similar thing where I wanted to load 1 asset that lead to another asset. The issue is that you need to extract both asssets or you will get the webpage not avail error. So yes, you would need to create an input stream for test2 as well.

There are other ways to extract assets other than using input streams. You will have to play around with making a directory in your apk and moving the file to a certain path, and using that path. It's a little confusing but can help if you plan to load many local assets in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a neat solution that works for all devices. But I would recommend you to first copy the files from Assets to Internal Directory (getFilesDir()). And then perform

```
webView.loadUrl("file://"+getFilesDir()+"/myHtml.html");
```